# how to get outer <li> tag with inside <li> or other tag text using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want output only outer li tag text.

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  html = BeautifulSoup("""

      <ul>

            <li><a href="#">B2B Marketing</a>
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="offerings/b2bmarketing/outboundai.php"> Campagin </a></li>
                        <li><b>Inbound AI </b>Enrich inbound leads</a></li>
                   </ul>
           </li>

           <li>Marketing Data Analysis
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="offerings/marketingdataanalysis/event360ai.php"><b>Event 360 AI </b></a></li>
                   </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Enrichment API</a>
          </li>


      </ul>

      """)

  print([i.text.strip() for i in html.findAll('li')])
```

Output is coming whole text of the html content.

```
['B2B Marketing\n\n Campagin \nInbound AI Enrich inbound leads', 'Campagin', 'Inbound AI Enrich inbound leads', 'Marketing Data Analysis\n          \nEvent 360 AI', 'Event 360 AI', 'Enrichment API\n\nAPI  Technographics, Firmographics, Intent data', 'API  Technographics, Firmographics, Intent data']
```

But

Output should be:-

```
  [
   'B2B Marketing : Campagin, Enrich inbound leads',
   'Marketing Data Analysis : Event 360 AI',
   'Enrichment API'
  ]
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: But you *aren't* interested in only the text of the outer `li` element; your requested output is a function of the contents of the `li` elements in the nested list as well.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<ul>
            <li><a href="#">B2B Marketing</a>
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="offerings/b2bmarketing/outboundai.php"> Campagin </a></li>
                        <li><b>Inbound AI </b>Enrich inbound leads</a></li>
                   </ul>
           </li>
           <li>Marketing Data Analysis
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="offerings/marketingdataanalysis/event360ai.php"><b>Event 360 AI </b></a></li>
                   </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Enrichment API</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
lis = doc.ul.lis
out = []
for li in lis:
  if li.b and li.b.nextText():
    li.removeElement('b')
  name = li.firstText() if li.firstText() else li.a.text
  tmp = ''
  for l in li.lis:
    tmp += l.text+','
  if tmp:
    out.append(name+':'+tmp[0:-1])
  else:
    out.append(name)
print (out)
```

Result:

```
['B2B Marketing:Campagin,Enrich inbound leads', 'Marketing Data Analysis:Event 360 AI', 'Enrichment API']
```

Comment: In out list 'Marketing Data Analysis: Event 360 AI ' 
Event 360 AI is not there

Comment: Your needs are really special, but I've met you:)